# Database Design: Multiple User Entities. Single or Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, schema

I am building a PHP app that has 3 basic entity types: Coach, Student, Lesson, where coaches create digital lessons for students. I'm using MySQL and innoDB tables.

**Requirements**

1. Coach and student login.
2. Coach can deliver a digital lesson specifically for a single student.

I'm unsure what is the best DB schema to use given the requirements. Here are two options:

**Option 1**
User (PK id, user_type (coach or student), firstname, lastname, email, password, etc...)
Lesson (PK id, FK coach_user_id (ref: User.id), FK student_user_id (ref: User.id), lesson_name, etc…)

**Pros:**
- One user table
- Each user has a unique ID and email
- Makes login auth easy with single table

**Cons:**
- No validation of user_type when a coach or student User.id is recorded as a FK in the lesson table. This problem will reoccur in any new table where a coach or student User.id needs to be recorded as a FK.
- Potential polymorphism issues and the need to normalise down the track.

**Option 2**
Coach (PK id, firstname, lastname, email, password, etc...)
Student (PK id, firstname, lastname, email, password, etc...)
Lesson (PK id, FK coach_id (ref: Coach.id), FK student_id (ref: Student.id), lesson_name, lesson_text, etc…)

**Pros:**
- Normalised DB schema. Independent coach, students entity tables.
- No user type validation issues. Coach ID and student ID FK's point independently to Coach.id and Student.id respectively.

**Cons:**
- Coach and student can have the same ID. (This can be solved though with ID prefixes e.g. C1001, S1001)
- Coach and student can have the same email.
- Login auth involves querying two 2 tables for single login page, or creating 2 different login pages and auth request types.

I'm really torn which is the best way to go. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, both of your approaches would work. The first one is more universal, and  capable of fitting various currently unknown requirements . If you choose it, I'd recommend to add concept of Role to the model - "user_type" is a role, and one user can be associated with different roles [at the same time]. Also, "The Data Model Resource Book" by Len Silverston is a great resource .

However, you may not always want your schema to be too general. You listed pros and cons for 2 approaches on very low level; I think that practicability is more important than particular technical issues (which can be overcome ). I'd put it that way :

1) Pros :

- easy to accommodate new features without major changes to schema
- very flexible
- easy to build cubes on top of the schema
- fits long term projects

Cons :

- requires more resources (experienced DBA/Data Model specialist[s], comparatively longer design time  )
- way more complex than (2)

2) Pros :

- fast delivery of first working version
- quite easy for understanding even by non-technical people (until it grows up)
- fits either small projects or projects with well-defined domains which [almost] never change

Cons :

- never ending refactoring of schema as new requirements come
- if project lives long enough, database becomes full of "not used anymore" columns(or other db objects) nobody wants to touch
- harder to enforce integrity

I hope it makes sense and helps you to make the right decision which fits your needs.

Comment: So from Option 1 you'd remove User.user_type and then create Role and User_Role tables to allow for a many to many relationship? Do you have a site with more info about this? ;)

Comment: Role table itself just defines different roles, like "Student", "Coach", etc . Then we need `user_role` link table. In some cases it's enough to have just `user_id`, `role_id` fields in it (with UNIQUE(`user_id, role_id`)). In others, you may want to add dates - from and through -for instance, user1 was a student in 2012, then he becomes coach, etc. Then you need another unique constraint, not `UNIQUE(user_id, role_id)`, but  `UNIQUE(user_id, role_id, date_from)`.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 looks better to me.

It will simplify your code when you don't care to distinguish students from coaches, and will be pretty much the same as option 2 if you want to distinguish them.

If you really need to validate the foreign keys you can use triggers to check if its a coach or not.

I'm not sure what you mean by *"Potential polymorphism issues and the need to normalise down the track."*.